# Architecture for form to handle a third-party API lookup in Django?

Tags: django

I have a Django site that's basically a bunch of neighbourhoods, one page per neighbourhood.

There is a form on the home page where the user can enter a zipcode, and the site will forward them to the correct page for their neighbourhood.

The lookup from zipcode<->neighbourhood ID is provided by a third-party API.

What is the most Django-ish way to implement the form with the third-party lookup on the home page? Some options I've considered:

1. Set the form to POST back to the home page, capture POST requests to the home page, look up the API response using `requests`, and then HttpResponseRedirect the user to the correct page.
2. Set the form to POST to another URL, and have an entirely separate view to handle the lookup and redirect.
3. I could not use POST, but instead use GET to `zipcode/<zipcode>`, and then forward again from that.

Are any of these preferable?

Of course, I could also add a JavaScript method on the home page to capture the form input, call the third-party API, parse the response, and forward the user. The disadvantage of this is obviously that it requires the user to have JavaScript.

Comment: Generally, lookups should be GETs. POSTs should be reserved for actions that modify data in your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with option 3.

As Daniel Roseman said, `GET` is the more appropriate method since this is an idempotent operation that doesn't change any state on the server. That view can do the lookup (using `requests`, like you said) and then do an HTTP redirect to the appropriate page.